# I need to compare the sum of one table to the sum of another table and only display when one is greater than the other

Tags: sql, having

here is my code

```
select sum(IV.total) as total, 
       IV.sono, 
       sum(SO.total) as total2 
  from tblInvoiceDetail as IV 
       left join tblSO as SO on IV.sono=SO.sono 
 where IV.sono not in (108428,108368) 
 group by IV.sono  
having sum(SO.total) < sum(IV.total) 
 order by IV.sono DESC
```

Comment: "here is my code"? Did you have a question?

Comment: seems correct ... and the questions is ?

Comment: And what's going wrong? Sample data and result would help others help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use subqueries to do so:

```
select IV.sono, ivtotal, sototal
  from (select sono, sum(total) ivtotal from tblInvoiceDetail group by sono) as IV
       LEFT JOIN
       (select sono, sum(total) sototal from tblSO group by sono) as SO 
       ON IV.sono = SO.sono
 where SO.sototal < IV.ivtotal
   and IV.sono not in (108428,108368) 
 order by IV.sono DESC
```